# How to loop through a number of elements, checking if they hold certain conditions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a small school project. It is a wheel of fortune kind of game. I have an alphabet displayed and each letter is clickable. When a player clicks on a letter and it happens to be a right guess - the letter shows on a word table. The player looses if points become 0, and I'm trying to make it so when a user opens all letters and will have more than 0  points he wins.

So, I want to loop through all boxes on a word table and check them all for two conditions: 1.if letter should be there and it is , 2.if the letter is shown(I do not use display none for hiding it, I made it a variable and loop through an array of words with different lengths, that is why I need to check if the letter is there and if it should be there).

At this point game stops after first right guess.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var counter = 0;
 var points = 3000;
    var gameinplay = false;
 //array of words and hints
    var words = [{word: "lambent", hint: "softly bright or radiant, 7 letters"}, 
     {word: "facetious", hint: "meant to be humorous or funny : not serious"}, 
     {word: "obfuscate", hint: "to be evasive, unclear, or confusing"}];
 //does a number of things when click start button
 $('#start').click(function(){
  gameinplay = true;
  //moves the wheel
        $('#wheel').addClass('rotate').delay(15000).queue(function(next){
            $('#wheel').removeClass('rotate');
            next();
        });      
        //shows hint when click start button 
  $('#hint').text(words[counter].hint).show();

  //shows points in the beginning
  $('#points').text(points + " points").show();

  //shows alphabet
  $('.letter').show();

  //changes start button to reset game
  $('#start').text("RESTART GAME").show();

  //loops through an array of words and hints each time start button clicked
  for (var i = 0; i < words[counter].word.length; i++) {
      $('.wordLetter').eq(i).attr('data-letter', words[counter].word.charAt(i));//assigns a letter value to each box
  }

  //resets the game to the next word
  counter = counter + 1;
    });

    //Make each letter an element - done!
 //Make each letter clickable
    $('.letter').click(function(){
     if (gameinplay) {
            var letter = $(this);
            var letterPresence = false;
            
            //Checks if this letter is in word  
            $('.wordLetter').each(function(){       
                if ($(this).attr('data-letter').toUpperCase() == letter.text()){ //checks if the letter pushed is the same letter in word 
                    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-letter')); //shows letter in word table 
                    letterPresence = true; //sets letterPresence equal to true   
                }   
            });
            if (letterPresence == true) {
                points += 1000; // adds points by a 1000 if letter was guessed wright
                $('#points').text(points + " points"); 
                $('.instructions').text("Right guess!").show(); //gives instructions
            } else {
                points -= 1000; // subtracts points by a 1000 if letter was not guessed wright
                $('#points').text(points + " points"); //shows total points
                $('.instructions').text("This letter is not in the word.").show(); //gives instructions
                if (points == 0){ //if points equal 0 game is over
                    $('#gameover').show(); //cancels display:none
                    gameinplay = false; //makes letters non clickable
                } //end if statement  
            }//end each loop
//This is where I need some help to figure out how to loop through all letters in a word
            $('.wordLetter').each(function(){
                //check if all letters are shown
                if($(this).attr('data-letter') != " " && $(this).is(":visible")){
                    $('#wongame').show();
                    gameinplay = false; 
                }
            });
        } //end if game in play         
    });
});
```

```css
#gameover, #wongame {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="wheel.js"></script>
 <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wheel.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="bootstrap.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <button id="start" class="button button1">START</button></div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <img id="logo" src="logo.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <h3 id="hint"></h3>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div >
       <img id="wheel" src="wheel_of_fortune.jpg" alt="wheel_of_fortune">
      </div>
   </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centerbottomrow">
       <h3 id="points"></h3>
       <h2 id="comment"></h2>
       <span class="letter">A</span>
       <span class="letter">B</span>
       <span class="letter">C</span>
       <span class="letter">D</span>
       <span class="letter">E</span>
       <span class="letter">F</span>
       <span class="letter">G</span>
       <span class="letter">H</span>
       <span class="letter">I</span>
       <span class="letter">J</span>
       <span class="letter">K</span>
       <span class="letter">L</span>
       <span class="letter">M</span>
     <span class="letter">N</span>
     <span class="letter">O</span>
     <span class="letter">P</span>
     <span class="letter">Q</span>
     <span class="letter">R</span>
     <span class="letter">S</span>
     <span class="letter">T</span>
     <span class="letter">U</span>
     <span class="letter">V</span>
     <span class="letter">W</span>
     <span class="letter">X</span>
     <span class="letter">Y</span>
     <span class="letter">Z</span>
     <h2 class="instructions"></h2>
     <h2 id="gameover">
      GAME OVER <br> Click restart button to begin a new game 
     </h2>
     <h2 id="wongame"> CONGRATULATION!<br> YOU WON!!!</h2>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centerbottomrow">
       <table>
         <tr>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
             <td data-letter="" class="wordLetter"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
    </div>  
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **"`. You have a `**` on line 94 in the JavaScript.

Comment: It shows error while run code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple things.  First I just created the word row and added the `<td>`'s dynamically which should allow for words of various lengths.   The easiest way to then check to see if the whole word has been found is to check the `text()` function for that row.  Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var counter = 0;
 var points = 3000;
    var gameinplay = false;
 //array of words and hints
    var words = [{word: "lambent", hint: "softly bright or radiant, 7 letters"}, 
     {word: "facetious", hint: "meant to be humorous or funny : not serious"}, 
     {word: "obfuscate", hint: "to be evasive, unclear, or confusing"}];
 //does a number of things when click start button
 $('#start').click(function(){
  gameinplay = true;
  //moves the wheel
        $('#wheel').addClass('rotate').delay(15000).queue(function(next){
            $('#wheel').removeClass('rotate');
            next();
        });      
        //shows hint when click start button 
  $('#hint').text(words[counter].hint).show();

  //shows points in the beginning
  $('#points').text(points + " points").show();

  //shows alphabet
  $('.letter').show();

  //changes start button to reset game
  $('#start').text("RESTART GAME").show();

  //Create the list of <td> for each word
  for (var i = 0; i < words[counter].word.length; i++) {
                      $('<td>')
                          .data('letter', words[counter].word[i])
                          .text('_')
                          .appendTo('.word-row');
  }

  //resets the game to the next word
  counter = counter + 1;
    });

    //Make each letter an element - done!
 //Make each letter clickable
    $('.letter').click(function(){
     if (gameinplay) {
            var letter = $(this);
            var letterPresence = false;
            
            //Checks if this letter is in word  
            $('.word-row>td').each(function(){       
                if ($(this).data('letter').toUpperCase() == letter.text()){ //checks if the letter pushed is the same letter in word 
                    $(this).text($(this).data('letter')); //shows letter in word table 
                    letterPresence = true; //sets letterPresence equal to true   
                }   
            });
            if (letterPresence == true) {
                points += 1000; // adds points by a 1000 if letter was guessed wright
                $('#points').text(points + " points"); 
                $('.instructions').text("Right guess!").show(); //gives instructions
            } else {
                points -= 1000; // subtracts points by a 1000 if letter was not guessed wright
                $('#points').text(points + " points"); //shows total points
                $('.instructions').text("This letter is not in the word.").show(); //gives instructions
                if (points == 0){ //if points equal 0 game is over
                    $('#gameover').show(); //cancels display:none
                    gameinplay = false; //makes letters non clickable
                } //end if statement  
            }//end each loop

//This is where I need some help to figure out how to loop through all letters in a word
 
            if ( $('.word-row').text() === words[counter].word) {
                $('#wongame').show();
                gameinplay = false;
            }               
        } //end if game in play         
    });
});
```

```css
#gameover, #wongame {
 display: none;
}
.word-row>td {
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="wheel.js"></script>
 <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wheel.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <button id="start" class="button button1">START</button></div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <img id="logo" src="logo.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centertoprow">
       <h3 id="hint"></h3>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div >
       <img id="wheel" src="wheel_of_fortune.jpg" alt="wheel_of_fortune">
      </div>
   </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centerbottomrow">
       <h3 id="points"></h3>
       <h2 id="comment"></h2>
       <span class="letter">A</span>
       <span class="letter">B</span>
       <span class="letter">C</span>
       <span class="letter">D</span>
       <span class="letter">E</span>
       <span class="letter">F</span>
       <span class="letter">G</span>
       <span class="letter">H</span>
       <span class="letter">I</span>
       <span class="letter">J</span>
       <span class="letter">K</span>
       <span class="letter">L</span>
       <span class="letter">M</span>
     <span class="letter">N</span>
     <span class="letter">O</span>
     <span class="letter">P</span>
     <span class="letter">Q</span>
     <span class="letter">R</span>
     <span class="letter">S</span>
     <span class="letter">T</span>
     <span class="letter">U</span>
     <span class="letter">V</span>
     <span class="letter">W</span>
     <span class="letter">X</span>
     <span class="letter">Y</span>
     <span class="letter">Z</span>
     <h2 class="instructions"></h2>
     <h2 id="gameover">
      GAME OVER <br> Click restart button to begin a new game 
     </h2>
     <h2 id="wongame"> CONGRATULATION!<br> YOU WON!!!</h2>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="centerbottomrow">
       <table>
         <tr class="word-row">
         </tr>
     </table>
    </div>  
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```